# Samsung Smart TV YouTube JavaScript Player API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, samsung-smart-tv

i was developed and launched an app for Samsung Smart TV
on(2011 TV) (SDK 2.5) and everything is ok.

and made it by YouTube JavaScript Player API v2
Now i'm trying to convert it to (2012 TV) (SDK 3.5)by use YouTube JavaScript Player API v3

im just change the version value  from [apiplayer?version=2&enablejsapi=1 ] to==>[apiplayer?version=3&enablejsapi=1 ]

but nothing shown on tv or emulator just show a youtube word but no video

this is my youtube create function

```
function createYoutube() {
if (Main.onLine && !youtubeCreated)
{
  youtubeCreated = true;
  var html = "<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' id='playerObject' style='width:507px; height:285.1px;'> "+
            "<param name='movie' value='http://youtube.googleapis.com/apiplayer?version=3&enablejsapi=1'></param>"+
            "<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'></param>"+
            "<param name='wmode' value='transparent'></param> "+
            "</object>";
  var player = document.getElementById("player")
  widgetAPI.putInnerHTML(player,html);
}
```

---

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady()
{

    YouTubePlayer = document.getElementById('playerObject');
    YouTubePlayer.addEventListener('onStateChange','onPlayerStateChange');
    YouTubePlayer.addEventListener('onError', 'onPlayerError');


    refreshPlayer();
}
```

i tried use http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3
but nothing changed .

Comment: And have you tried API version=2 on 2012? What it the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version=2 implies that the ActionScript 2 runtime will be used. (This version has been deprecated for a few years now and will be shut down soon.) version=3 implies that the ActionScript 3 runtime will be used. It might be that your platform doesn't support the ActionScript 3 runtime, in which case you'd need to follow up with Samsung.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are using the wrong param use this

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?&enablejsapi=1&version=3&controls=1&fs=1"></param>
```

insted of

```
<param name='movie' value='http://youtube.googleapis.com/apiplayer?version=3&enablejsapi=1'></param>
```